# Disconnection Bluetooth device C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I write a software to connect to BLE with C#.

I used the code:

https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename/blob/master/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename/MainPage.xaml.cs

However, I can't disconnect the device...
The line device.Dispose() doesn't work for me..

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ means nothing. Can you be more specific? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: Aha. That was PITA for us. However IClosable helped.